# Insertion comparison #'s seem too big

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, selection, insertion

I am confused if these comparison numbers are supposed to be this large in value for a vector with 100 random two-digit numbers. Full program --> safe link: https://ideone.com/oybDbD   The program output is at the bottom page of the link. Appreciate input.

```
int insertionSort (vector<int> &v) {
    int j, temp, counter = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < v.size(); i++) {
        j = i;

        while (++counter && j > 0 && v[j] < v[j-1]){
            temp = v[j];
            v[j] = v[j-1];
            v[j-1] = temp;
            j--;
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The average case performance of insertion sort is `O(N^2)` (see the [wiki entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort)). For your vector of 100 elements, the expected number of comparisons is therefore `O(10000)`. Coming out with 2656 or, in your second run, 4995, comparisons is therefore *lower* than you might otherwise expect.

Comment: Just to clarify, the expected numbers of comparisons for insertion sort is 10, 000? Thanks for helping :)

Comment: @Lightypulse: Not quite. The average number of comparisons is `O(N^2)`, which evaluates to `O(10000)` in this case. Expectation values get into stats, which is a different ballgame. My apologies for the lack of clarity there. Also, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17055341/why-is-insertion-sort-%CE%98n2-in-the-average-case) may help you better understand what's going on.

Comment: @Lightypulse: If my answer has been helpful to you, feel free to upvote or accept it by clicking the arrows or check mark by it.